# empty frame_id when converting sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 to sensor_msgs/Image

Tags: ros, pcl, iai-kinect2, frame-id, depth-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using [iai_kinect2](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2)(ROS Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04) to get a depth cloud from my Kinect2  in the form `sensor_msgs/Image`. Then, it is converted to `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` using [depth_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/depth_image_proc) to do all the filtering operations using pcl. Finally, I want to convert the filtered `point_cloud` back to `sensor_msgs/Image` and for that, I am using [pcl_ros/CloudToImage](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros/Tutorials/CloudToImage) to get `sensor_msgs/Image` (on topic `/kinect2/filtered_image`). It compiled properly but during run time, when I try to visualize it in RVIZ, I get the following :

```
MessageFilter [target=kinect2_link ]: Discarding message from [unknown_publisher] due to empty frame_id.  This message will only print once.
```

When I do `rostopic echo /kinect2/filtered_image`, I get:

```
header: 
  seq: 2139
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: ''
height: 1
width: 68227
encoding: bgr8
is_bigendian: 0
step: 204681
data: [0, 0, 181, 209, 216, 179, 207, 214, 179, 207, 214, 0, 0, 0, 175, 204, 211, 176, 205, 212, 176, 205, 210, 177, 206, 211, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 179, 207, 214, 179, 208, 215, 181, 210, 217, 0, 0, 0, 178, 207, 214, 179, 208, 215, 180, 209, 216, 175, 204, 209, 175, 205, 210, 174, 203, 210, 0, 0, 0, 174, 203, 210, 175, 204, 211, 174, 203, 210, 176, 204, 211, 177, 205, 212, 0, 0, 0, 178, 207, 212, 180, 209, 214, 178, 206, 213, 179, 208, 215, 177, 209, 215, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 180, 209, 216, 174, 203, 208, 174, 203, 208, 176, 205, 210, 174, 203, 208, 175, 204, 209, 175, 205, 210, 175, 205, 210, 175, 204, 211, 175, 204, 211, 173, 205, 211, 172, 204, 210, 173, 205, 211, 173, 205, 211, 176, 205, 212, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 179, 208, 215, 171, 203, 209, ....... ]
```

It looks like there is some problem here. It does not have any `time stamp` or `frame_id`. Also, the encoding is `bgr8`, shouldn't it be `16UC1`?

**EDIT :**
As suggested in the answer, after copying the header from the input point cloud into the image and then if I visualize the published image in RVIZ, I get the following issue and RVIZ shuts down :

```
[ WARN] [1451938112.487114384]: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Zero sized texture surface on texture ROSImageTexture0 face 0 mipmap 0. Probably, the GL driver refused to create the texture. in GLTexture::_createSurfaceList at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLTexture.cpp (line 420)
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::RenderingAPIException'
  what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Zero sized texture surface on texture ROSImageTexture0 face 0 mipmap 0. Probably, the GL driver refused to create the texture. in GLTexture::_createSurfaceList at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLTexture.cpp (line 420)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Does anyone have any idea why is this happening? Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223487/empty-frame_id-when-converting-sensor_msgs/pointcloud2-to-sensor_msgs/image/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2016-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the `CloudToImage` page:

> Given a dense cloud, you can efficiently grab the rgb image from it as a sensor_msgs::Image

The CloudToImage example is expecting a colored point cloud, and is trying to extract the RGB image from it; not the depth image. This is why you're getting an RGB image.

It looks like the missing frame and timestamp is a separate issue. Perhaps `pcl::toROSMsg()` isn't preserving header information as it should. This is probably a bug in pcl_conversions, but you can work around it by copying the header from your input point cloud to the final image before you publish it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2016-01-04**:
Thanks @ahendrix! Yes, I am giving Color Point cloud. Is there a way to get the `depth_image` in the form `sensor_msgs/Image` from the dense Point Cloud? I want to use it with `depthimage_to_laserscan`. Also regarding your second part of the answer, I have updated the original question. TIA!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-04**:
I'm sure you can reconstruct a depth image from a point cloud, but I haven't done it myself, so I'm not sure where to start. You may also want to look into the pointcloud_to_laserscan package, and avoid the need to convert back to a depth image.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-04**:
I'm not sure why rviz is crashing. Are you trying to display an RGB image in a depth image display or something weird like that?

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2016-01-04**:
Yes.. I have looked into `pointcloud_to_laserscan` package but my only concern with that is it might be less efficient than `depthimage_to_laserscan` but again I am not sure how efficient it will be to generate depth image from a point cloud.